# calling oauth2 login service from angular2

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0

Can any one help me out in calling oauth2 login service using angular 2 or 4.

I am able to call them from rest client successfully , how ever I have no clue

to call from angular js.

post request is ::
http://localhost:8989/auth/oauth/token?username=guest&password=guest123&grant_type=password

and I have to set Basic Authentication Client Id and Secret  with the same request.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After few hours struggle, addressed solution for my for my problem , I just posting answer for the people who are facing the same issue. Make sure CORS settings in server side.

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core'
import {Http,Headers,RequestOptions } from '@angular/http'

@Injectable()
export class DashBoardService {

constructor(private http :Http){

}
public allCards(){
//?username=guest&password=guest123&grant_type=password
let username: string = 'service-account-1';
let password: string = 'service-account-1-secret';
let data ={"username":"guest","password":"guest123","grant_type":"password","client_id":"service-account-1"};
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));
headers.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });


return this.http.post("http://localhost:8989/oauth/token?username=guest&password=guest123&grant_type=password",
"",options);

}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are writing a Single Page App that calls APIs - is that right?

**DETAILS ON LOGINS FOR SINGLE PAGE APPS**

I have been writing a tutorial based blog that you may find useful. The blog is very detailed, but the first thing to understand is the moving parts:

- Your **Angular App** uses the OAuth 2.0 Implicit Flow to log users in
- An **Authorization Server** externalizes security from your SPA
- Your SPA calls **OAuth 2.0 Secured APIs** with access tokens after login

Once you understand the above separation, you next need to understand the OAuth messages. Maybe start by browsing this page:

[SPA Overview](http://authguidance.com/2017/09/24/basicspa-overview/)

If you find it useful there are follow on pages on how to run my samples, details on OAuth messages and so on.