# Angular Spring Oauth2 Invalid credentials

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-oauth2

When I try to call login api endpoint on my Angular app I get the html rendered with the message "Invalid Credentials" but if I try to access the login endpoint on the browser I can do login successfully. I'm also able to get the token on postman and invoke my api.

AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2AuthorizationServer extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("dataSource")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired 
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    @Autowired 
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Autowired 
    private PasswordEncoder oauthClientPasswordEncoder;


    @Bean
    JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        ((DefaultAccessTokenConverter) converter.getAccessTokenConverter())
                .setUserTokenConverter(userAuthenticationConverter());

        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenEnhancer tokenEnhancer() {
        return new CustomTokenEnhancer();
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler oauthAccessDeniedHandler() {
        return new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) {
        oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()")
                .passwordEncoder(oauthClientPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public UserAuthenticationConverter userAuthenticationConverter() {
        DefaultUserAuthenticationConverter defaultUserAuthenticationConverter = new DefaultUserAuthenticationConverter();

        defaultUserAuthenticationConverter.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        return defaultUserAuthenticationConverter;
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(final AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
        TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
        tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(
        List.of(new CustomTokenEnhancer(), accessTokenConverter()));


        endpoints.accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter())
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain);
    }

}
```

ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class OAuth2ResourceServer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String SECURED_PATTERN = "/secured/**";
    private static final String SECURED_READ_SCOPE = "#oauth2.hasScope('read')";
    private static final String SECURED_WRITE_SCOPE = "#oauth2.hasScope('write')";

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources.resourceId("resource-server-rest-api").stateless(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.cors()
            .and()
            .antMatcher("/api/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**", "/login**", "/error**", "/api/auth/**")
            .permitAll();

        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/**")
            .authenticated();

    }
}
```

WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
public class Oauth2WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired 
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Autowired 
    private PasswordEncoder userPasswordEncoder;

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
                auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(userPasswordEncoder);
    }

    private static final String[] CSRF_IGNORE = {"/login/**", "/signup/**"};

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.cors()
            .and()
            .antMatcher("/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**", "/login**", "/error**", "/api/auth/**")
            .permitAll();

        http.cors()
            .and()
            .formLogin();

        http.httpBasic()
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .ignoringAntMatchers(CSRF_IGNORE)
            .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())
            .and()
            .addFilterAfter(new CustomCsrfFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
    }

    private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
        HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
        repository.setHeaderName(CustomCsrfFilter.CSRF_COOKIE_NAME);
        return repository;
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList ("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList(("*")));

        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"));
        //applyPermitDefaultValues(
                UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
                source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
                return source;
    }
}
```

Angular Login Service

```
login(email: string, password: string): Observable<any> {

    const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' , 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true'})
    };

    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/login', {  
        username: email,
        password: password
    }, 
    httpOptions).pipe(tap((resp: any) => {

        console.log(resp);

        this.loggedIn.next(true);
        this.saveToken(resp.user.token);

        if(resp && resp.user && resp.user.name) {
            localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify( resp.user.name));
        }}), 
        catchError( err => {
            throw err;
        })
    );
}
```

Update: I think that my problem is that the user / pass is not arriving to spring security so I'm having this error

> 2020-02-22 15:43:38.452 DEBUG 9912 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : User '' not found
>   2020-02-22 15:43:38.458 DEBUG 9912 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials
>   org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials

here are spring security full logs:
https://easyupload.io/dkjqi8

Comment: and what does your spring security debug logs tell you?

Comment: I just have the spring security query on the logs. Do I have to pass the username and parameters in a different way on angular? Do I have to create a new controller to handle the login on Spring boot?

Comment: i will ask you again, what does your security debug logs tell you?

Comment: @ThomasAndolf Where can I check those logs?

Comment: when you run your spring application, it will write logging to the console, and then by adding logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG to the application.properties file

Comment: Try to follow the below URL and let me know,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48904762/calling-oauth2-login-service-from-angular2

Comment: @ThomasAndolf 2020-02-22 14:13:00.691 DEBUG 20192 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : User '' not found
2020-02-22 14:13:00.699 DEBUG 20192 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials

Comment: Dont post it in the comments! Edit your question and add the full logs there....

Comment: @ThomasAndolf I've uploaded the entire file log because it's too big to put everything here. The problem is that the user is not arriving properly to spring security. please check https://easyupload.io/dkjqi8

Comment: dont upload it, put it in a pastebin

Comment: then debug UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter and you will find your answer there

Comment: I already did that, i got null on the username and password.